# Automating modification of tfstate

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a Gitlab CI/CD Pipeline that deploys to CloudFront.  Each app has some variables defined as pipeline variables like so:

```
APP_CONTEXT=/myapp
S3_BUCKET=abx-dev-myapp
EXTERNAL_ACCESS=true
```

We have our CloudFront Terraform managed and the TF files are stored in GIT in a separate repo, say `static-appstate`. The configuration uses and S3 backend to store the `.tfstate` and uses Dynamo for locking.  The actual `.tf` definitions are stored in the repo mentioned.

The Pipeline has a Terraform configuration stage that reads these variables, clones the `static-appstate` repo, makes appropriate changes to the `.tf` file to add Behaviors to CloudFront and create Origins are required and performs a `terraform apply`.

All this works fine, however, I am wondering how to update the actual `.tf` file.  Without the update the main configuration will never be updated in the repository and subsequent pipeline invocations will not have the current configuration.

If I execute a `git commit` to commit the changes I have the issues of contention and possible conflicts if two pipelines for different apps are simultaneously running in parallel.

The only solution at the moment is that the `TF` files are being manually updated.  Is manual management the only solution?  It would be nice if my Pipeline could somehow auto-update the `TF` configuration based on the app metadata.

So ideally, when a new app is onboarded, the above variables are the only thing required, the Pipeline would check out the state repo, update the `TF` file to add in the new config, check in the new `TF` file and perform the Terraform application so the `TF` state in the repo, the `.tfstate` in S3 and the CloudFront config, all will be current.

Comment: This feels like maybe too big a problem to give a definitive answer to -- a lot will depend on various constraints of your environment -- but my first thought here is to think about having an extra central "pipeline" that somehow consumes the data gathered by all of the others and merges it all together into a single Terraform configuration. Then you can hopefully make sure there can only ever be one active run of that pipeline and avoid the write contention issues, but arrange for the other pipelines to trigger the central one so that the updates will still happen promptly.

Comment: thanks, yeah, I realize this is a rather challenging issue in terms of design.  I was hoping for a rather simple solution that does not involve additional pipelines.  I am wondering how common is the practice of an automated system making changes to the TF configuration or if this even should be done by an automated system.  I was thinking one solution is to use a single queue for the update so that the process will be sequential.

Comment: I came up with an alternative solution, I used a S3 datasource and read the variable from S3.  Each app will download the config and update it as needed.  Contention is not handled a the moment.